# Android web view is not being executed the <script> tag

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I'm trying to render the HTML page in the android web view. It is a text editor Quill. It works from the desktop browser: the form and the content are being rendered, and the content might be changed by the user. But if I try to render the same HTML in the web view, it shows only content without the editing form, seems like the part of the code, which includes the library, is not being executed

```
<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
<script>
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
```

I've tried to enable the JavaScript by updating the webView's settings and other flags, but it doesn't help.

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val chromeClient = WebChromeClient()

//        binding.webView.webChromeClient = chromeClient
        binding.webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        binding.webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
//        binding.webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
//        binding.webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
//        binding.webView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
//        binding.webView.settings.displayZoomControls = true
//        binding.webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
        binding.webView.settings.defaultTextEncodingName = "utf-8"
        binding.webView.settings.pluginState = WebSettings.PluginState.ON
//        binding.webView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        binding.webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
        binding.webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

        binding.buttonFirst.setOnClickListener {
//            binding.webView.loadUrl(getUri())
            binding.webView.loadData(getHtml(),"text/html", "UTF-8")
//            launchCustomTab()
        }

    }
```

Here is the HTML string

```
<!-- Include stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
  
  <p><span class="ql-size-small">Text size Small</span></p><p>Text size Usual</p>
<p><span class="ql-size-large">Text size Large</span></p><p><span class="ql-size-huge">Text size Huge</span></p>
<p><br></p><p><strong>Bold</strong></p><p><em>Italic</em></p><p><u>Underline</u></p><p><br></p>
<p>Unordered list (bullets)</p>
<ul>
  <li>bulet 1</li>
  <li>bulet 2</li>
  <li><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">bulet 3</span></li>
</ul><p><br></p><p><br></p><p>Ordered list (1. 2. 3.)</p>
<ol>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
</ol><p><br></p><p>Text alignment Left</p><p class="ql-align-center">Text alignment Center</p>
<p class="ql-align-right">Text alignment Right</p><p><br></p><p class="ql-indent-1">Left Indent</p><p><br></p>
<ul>
  <li>Right Indent</li>
  <li class="ql-indent-1">da</li>
  <li>awef</li>
</ul><p><br></p><p><br></p>
<p><a href="https://dev.aws.amazingdiscoveries.org/" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Insert link</a></p>
</div>

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
<script>
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
</script>
```

How it looks like in the desktop web editor (I was using  [this](https://jsonformatter.org/html-viewer) one)

[image]

And here how it looks (the same HTML inside of my web view )

[image]

As you can see, there isn't any editing form on the top, and the "text size" lines are not being increased or reduced which means the script didn't work.

So is there any way to run a script block inside of the web view?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to `addJavascriptInterface` in the activity:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavascriptInterface(this, webView), "HTMLOUT");
```

Then override onPageCommitVisible such that it injects via:

```
@Override
public void onPageCommitVisible(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url);
    view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML)"); // convert all javascript to HTML
    Log.v("", "url (passed): " + url + " < view.getUrl(): " + view.getUrl());
}
```